# Cronjob Bash not exporting

Tags: bash, cron

I have written the following script to run for when users have last logged in.  I am trying to export a cronjob to a .out file.  For some reason, I cannot get it to export.

```
#!/bin/bash
for User in $(cd /home;ls --hide=lost+found); do
echo "$User online since:"
who | awk '{ print "\tUser: "$1" - Terminal: "$2" - "$3" "$4}'
NOW=$(date +%s -d "Jan 1, 1980 00:00:01")
USR=$(lastlog |awk ' {print $1, ":",$5,$6,$9 } ' | grep $User)
USRDATE=$(echo $USR | cut -d ":" -f2)
(( USRDATE = $(date --date "$USRDATE" +%s) / 86400 ))
(( NOW = NOW/86400 ))
(( DAYS = NOW - USRDATE ))
done
FILE="/home/Mike/watchuser"
OUTPUTFILE="/tmp/watchuser.out"
if [ "$1" == 'out' ]
then
FILE = $OUTPUTFILE
fi
done
```

I believe the bash was moved to the correct directory /home/Mike/watchuser.

```
[root@ip-10-245-82-234 ec2-user]# ls -l /home/Mike/watchuser                      
-rwxr--r--. 1 Mike student 564 Oct  3 20:50 /home/Mike/watchuser
```

Also, when ls -l of the /tmp/ folder, I reiceve the following:

```
[root@ip-10-245-82-234 ec2-user]# ls -l /tmp/                                     
total 4
-rw-------. 1 Mike Mike 34 Dec 31  1969 crontab.RJIkgB
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  0 Oct  3 21:57 watchuser.out
```

here is my /etc/crontab edit : 
    */10 * * * * Mike /home/Mike/watchuser >> /tmp/watchuser.out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. Because you have some mistakes.

First of all, your script should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for User in $(cd /home;ls --hide=lost+found); do
echo "$User online since:"
who | awk '{ print "\tUser: "$1" - Terminal: "$2" - "$3" "$4}'
NOW=$(date +%s -d "Jan 1, 1980 00:00:01")
USR=$(lastlog |awk ' {print $1, ":",$5,$6,$9 } ' | grep $User)
USRDATE=$(echo $USR | cut -d ":" -f2)
(( USRDATE = $(date --date "$USRDATE" +%s) / 86400 ))
(( NOW = NOW/86400 ))
(( DAYS = NOW - USRDATE ))
done
FILE="/home/radu/watchuser"
OUTPUTFILE="/tmp/watchuser.out"
if [ "$1" == 'out' ]
then
FILE=$OUTPUTFILE  # you had an error here
fi                # and another one error here
```

And second, edit the crontab entries using `crontab -e` command (by default this will edit the current logged-in users crontab) and add the following line:

```
*/10 * * * * /home/Mike/watchuser >> /tmp/watchuser.out
```

...It doesn't need **your name** in front of the path to the script.

More about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: if he's using `/etc/crontab`, the 6th field *needs* to be the user name under which to run this.

Comment: @roadmr No, it's not the case. I bet that he is using `/tmp/crontab.RJIkgB` as you can see from his output of `ls -l /tmp/` command.

Comment: good catch, then he's wrong when he says (last line) "here is my /etc/crontab" :)

Comment: @roadmr Ok, I edited my answer to be clear.

Comment: Ahh, that could be it.  It is odd that it shows the year of 1969.  Any idea how to change that to the watchuser.out?

Comment: @Macenbro Use `sudo rm crontab.RJIkgB` - there is no problem. Normally a crontab file location should be `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER`.